# iOS >> Embedding YouTube Video Using UIWebView - Video is Not Playing

Tags: ios, youtube, embed

I'm trying to play a YouTube video in my app. It seems like I get to right place, but the video is not playing. I'm running the app on an actual device (not on the simulator).

this is the code I'm using:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *htmlString = @"<html><head>\
    <meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = 320\"/></head>\
    <body style=\"background:#000;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px\">\
    <iframe id=\"ytplayer\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"320\" height=\"240\"\
    src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID&feature?autoplay=1\"\
    frameborder=\"0\"/>\
    </body></html>";

//VIDEO_ID holds the video embedded code I get from YouTube

    [self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com"]];

}
```

The YouTube player is loading, but when I click on the PLAY button I get "This video is currently unavailable":

[image]

I tested the embedded video id (copy&paste into a web page) and it finds the related video (i.e. I assume I have the correct video id).

Anyone has any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like that specific video isn't available for mobile or something. Did you try another video-ID?

Comment: Hi Rob, I've tried several different videos. How can I tell if a certain video is "available for mobile"?

Comment: any luck in solving it? i'm stuck with the same problem!

Comment: anyone solved this issue ? i also stuck with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it was because I was using a custom user agent in my webview so youtube wasn't serving the proper video.

Comment: could you explain a bit more? I am stuck on this

Comment: @Jango Do you at any point in your application set a custom user agent for your web views?  So for instance when your application connects to a web server your app responds with something different than the default I am an iPhone?  Code to do this would looks something like:

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Your user agent", @"UserAgent", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];

and would usually get changed in your AppDelegate, but not always.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the url you are using:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID&feature?autoplay=1
```

Should be:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID?feature&autoplay=1
```

This is because the url itself is `http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID` and the parameters are feature and autoplay=1.

Cheers
Morten